# Will a router's bandwidth override what the ISP says you have?

Tags: networking, router, internet-connection, isp

I'm networking illiterate, and I wish to acquire a bit more information about networking.

Say, for example, I got a package from Verizon that said your connection will be ~20 mb/s, but I got a router that allows for ~100 mb/s. What would my internet connection actually be? I assume it'd be the ~20 mb/s, but I'm not sure, if so, then what would be the point of getting a router with the ability to have ~100mb/s? Why not get one that goes along with your package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will always be limited by the slowest piece in the chain.  In this case, Verizon is slower than your home router, so you will be limited to what you pay for with Verizon.

The point in getting a faster router (be in 100mb/s, 1000 mb/s etc is to increase speed between your local machines.  SO if you have 2 computers in your home, and you want to transfer a file between them, so long as they are both 100mb/s capable, then the file can be transferred at that speed.  This is beneficial for instance, if you wanted to play a movie from your PC via streaming over your local network to your PS3 or Xbox.

Comment: The main point in faster routers, for most people, is to sell faster routers.